# I can't get PHPUnit to run - Failed opening required 'SebastianBergmann/Diff/autoload.php'

Tags: php, phpunit

I installed PHPUnit via pear and I brought uploaded the required PHP files into the account.

I setup php.ini with every possible include path I could imagine...I know it is using the proper php.ini file because when I update it ..along with the error it shows the include paths change (below).....when I do a search of the server it simply doesn't find any folder named "SebastianBergmann"...I dont know what to do...please help..

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'SebastianBergmann/Diff/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/admin/inc:/home/limber/public_html/limber/plugin/PHPUnit:/usr/local/bin/phpunit') in /home/limber/public_html/limber/plugin/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 69

Call Stack:
    0.0001     635368   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0029    1109328   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:46
    0.0029    1110056   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
    0.0047    1578072   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:150
    0.0047    1578072   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:104
    0.0049    1622128   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:168
    0.0055    1787856   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:77
    0.0055    1788000   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:76
    0.0055    1800264   9. include_once('/home/limber/public_html/limber/test/public_html/limber/core/NumTest.php') /usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:92
    0.0058    1870848  10. include_once('/home/limber/public_html/limber/plugin/PHPUnit/Autoload.php') /home/limber/public_html/limber/test/public_html/limber/core/NumTest.php:3

root@host [/home/limber/public_html/limber/test/public_html/limber/core]# `pear config-get php_bin` -i | grep -E Configurati
on\ File\|include_path
Failed loading xdebug.so:  xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading xdebug.so:  xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
include_path => .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/admin/inc:/home/limber/public_html/limber/plugin/PHPUnit => .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/admin/inc:/home/limber/public_html/limber/plugin/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I installed phpunit via pear which gave me 3.7.*, when I download and uploaded the php code from git I downloaded 3.8...when I downloaded the 3.7 PHP code it all worked properly.